Collecting page data ...Error: Failed to collect configuration for /_not-found
I'm trying to create my first Next.js App Router project and I am having issues to build it for the first time. Iḿ getting the following error:
    ❯ npm run build

> qbits-nextjs@0.1.0 build
> next build

   ▲ Next.js 15.0.3
   - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...

warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
   Collecting page data  ...Error: Failed to collect configuration for /_not-found
    at <unknown> (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1131:23)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:153:20) {
  [cause]: TypeError: c(...).createContext is not a function
      at 8555 (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/.next/server/chunks/19.js:3:67092)
      at t (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
      at 9002 (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/.next/server/chunks/19.js:3:66870)
      at t (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
      at 9611 (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/.next/server/app/_not-found/page.js:1:2205)
      at Function.t (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
      at async getLayoutOrPageModule (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/app-dir-module.js:33:15)
      at async collectAppPageSegments (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/build/segment-config/app/app-segments.js:50:45)
      at async (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1129:28)
}

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /_not-found
    at <unknown> (/home/localuser/projects/personal/qbits-nextjs/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1234:15) {
  type: 'Error'
}

The error happens for every route, the page, layout and route.tsx files are all very simple, just a template. I tried everything, and I keep getting this error.
Any help will be greatly appreaciated!
